# How do I define a vector of values that contain the first occurrence of a variable in a group in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working with panel data with varying times of treatments. The data looks something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
city<-letters[1:20]
year<-c(2004,2008, 2011, 2016, 2021)
df<-expand.grid(city=city, year=year)
treatment_indices<-sample(1:nrow(df), size=50, replace=F)

df$treatment<-rep(0,nrow(df))
df$treatment %in% treatment_indices

df$treatment<-ifelse(row.names(df) %in% treatment_indices, 1, 0)
df %>% 
  arrange(city, year)
df%>%
filter(city=='a')
```

In order to make the `did` package work, I need to define a vector that contains the *first* period in which a treatment occurs. So, if my code is really reproducible (I hope so) then the variable `period` for city `a` should be a vector, length 5, of the value `2008` (e.g. the second year in the data-set). Thank you.

**Solution**
Integrating @Akrun's suggestion below, this provided what I needed.

```
df %>% 
arrange(city, year) %>% 
group_by(city) %>% 
#This returns the full row where the first treatment occurred in anuy and all groups where a treatment occurred. 
slice(match(1, treatment)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(city) %>% 
#This creates a new `period` variable for use in `did`
# it is the same as the matched year returned in which the first treatment occurred
  mutate(period=year) %>% 
#This is then rejoined to the original dataframe matching on city, year and treatment
  right_join(., df, by=c("city", "year", "treatment")) %>% 
#Groups are formed by city
  group_by(city) %>% 
#Then the `period` variable, which should be mostly filled with NAfor the years in which the treatment did not occurr is filled with the values of the first year in which the treatment occurred
  fill(period, .direction="downup") %>% 
#Arrange for viewing
  arrange(city, year)
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(city) %>% summarise(first = match(1, treatment))`

Comment: That does pick out the position of the first year that there is a treatment, but I need a `period` for `filter(df, city=="a")` to somehow equal `2008` for each instance of `city=="a"`. If that makes sense.

Comment: Then, probably you need `df %>% arrange(city, year) %>% group_by(city) %>% slice(match(1, treatment)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: OK, this was helpful, but it still only returned the rows that contained the first match. I needed to go further and create a variable that was filled with the year in which the first treatment occurred for each city. I have edited my code above to provide my solution, integrating @akrun 's help.

Comment: Please show the expected output for the input so that it is more easier to crosscheck